# Angular 2 Display Loading Message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm  a beginner in Angular 2 and I have a scenario whee there is a directive within a directive and the inner directive is loaded 10 times. Is there a way to show a loading message in the outer directive till all the inner DOM content is loaded? The `docs` value is populated by calling a service which populates the values.Right now I have the following code..

Outer Component Template:

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [Component1, Component2],
  template: `
        <div id="parent" class="parentDiv">
            <div id="scrolling">
                <div [hidden]="isLoading">Loading... </div>
                <div id="docs" *ngFor="#doc of docs">
                        <inner-doc *ngFor="#doc of doc.getDoc()" [doc]="doc"></inner-doc>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
  `
```

Inner Component Template:

```
@Component ({
  selector: 'inner-doc',
  inputs: ['doc', 'body'],
  template: `
        <div>
            <div class="Title"><div class="titleText" [innerHtml]="getTitle()"></div></div>
            <div class="Body"><div class="bodyText" [innerHtml]="getBody()"></div></div>
</div>
`
```

Having the following code in outer component using `ngAfterViewChecked` to switch `Loading` message once the inner directive gets loaded doesn't work well...

```
 ngAfterViewChecked(){
  this.isLoading=true;
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
  constructor (cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  this.isLoading=false;
  this.cdr=cdr;
  }
```

Any help with a working example would be great :)

Comment: How do you populate the `docs` variable in outer component? Is it through subscribing to a method in a service class? If so, you must set the value of `isLoading` variable within that service method, since it is executed asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks! That works..Post it as answer!

Comment: funny thing is you never mentioned `SERVICE` in your whole ducking question. Thanks to @SajithDilshan that he could see through your mind. No offence intended, Edit your question please

Comment: Done! Looks like we both were looking at the wrong place unlike @SajithDilshan who found out where exactly the issue was!

Comment: Glad I could help. Same thing happened to me more than once. Using life-cycle hooks can be a bit tricky with asynchronous service calls.