# Angular 2, display loading icon until page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm trying to make my page display a loading icon until all elements on my page have loaded. Currently I'm using jQuery to do this:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $(".page-loading").fadeOut("slow");;
  });
```

This waits for the page to load and then hides the loading icon, but does not wait for all the components to load, as once the loading icon fades out you still see data being pushed into elements.

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100919/angular-2-display-loading-message) Stack Overflow answer, but this isn't really what I'm trying to achieve. Is there another way to go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234211/how-to-set-animation-on-first-element-on-loading/36234670#36234670